# how to display a text for a link and also have some text?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

In a column I wanna display a text for a link and also some text. My column have to look like this: `Here is the link where I can find an **important document**` and the `important document` it's a link.

All I can do is to display `important document` and if I wanna type some text I can't, because the link it's activate. 
How to add text in the same column with a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, a link is applied to a **whole cell**. You cannot apply a link to just a few words of text in a cell. That's just how Excel works.

Don't shoot the messenger.